# npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...w2BfLygJAO9ZBvYIqZTld'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Got the above error while creating a new React App.

command: $npx create-react-app yourblog

Node --version v12.16.2
npx --version 6.14.4

[See error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQK0Z.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Clean npm cache and run command again!

**$npm cache clean --force**